# Graphic app for launch etl with parameters

Tags: etl, talend, app-launcher

I use Talend to develop ETLs the problem is that I need to make interfaces to run them.

With Talend I only can run it using command line, exist any application (web if is posible) to launch the ETLs? The app is realy simple I only need to run commands in a application server with some parameters.

Answer (score 1):

**Talend Integration Suite**, the subscription version of Talend, comes with a scheduler and web-based console that allows you to call your jobs with any set of context parameters.  You can call jobs at a scheduled time, or as a reaction to an external event (such as a file appearing in some directory).

With that version of the product, you can also deploy your job as a WebService and invoke it via SOAP (including parameter passing).

As you are probably using **Talend Open Studio**, the GPL-licensed version, that answer might not help you much, but if you can afford to switch to Talend Integration Suite, I would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think there is not such thing.
 
Nevertheless, you can launch jar file using [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) for any java app(just calling jar from a class or a [Servlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)) or [JAWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start). Hope it helps.